# Typing a long function in TEX

Tags: equations

I can't shrink this further,

```
\begin{equation}
y[x]=-\frac{(-1)^{5/6} \left(\text{AiryAi}\left[-(-1)^{2/3} (-2+i x)\right] \text{AiryBi}\left[2 (-1)^{2/3}\right]-\text{AiryAi}\left[2
(-1)^{2/3}\right] \text{AiryBi}\left[-(-1)^{2/3} (-2+i x)\right]\right)}{\text{AiryAiPrime}\left[2 (-1)^{2/3}\right] \text{AiryBi}\left[2 (-1)^{2/3}\right]-\text{AiryAi}\left[2
(-1)^{2/3}\right] \text{AiryBiPrime}\left[2 (-1)^{2/3}\right]}}\)
\end{equation}
```

Does anyone know how that can be done? It goes out of the margins.

Thanks

Comment: Unrelated: Use `\mathrm` not `\text`. (`\mathrm` is not affected by style changes)

Comment: If you use the standard notations `Ai` and `Bi` your formula might work more or less as is, depending on font size and width of the text block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can  use `\splitfrac` from `mathtools`:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{mathtools}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{equation}
    y[x]=-\frac{\splitfrac{(-1)^{5/6} \bigl(\text{AiryAi}\left[-(-1)^{2/3} (-2+i x)\right] \text{AiryBi}\left[2 (-1)^{2/3}\right]}{-\text{AiryAi}\left[2
    (-1)^{2/3}\right] \text{AiryBi}\left[-(-1)^{2/3} (-2+i x)\right]\bigr)}}{\splitfrac{\text{AiryAiPrime}\left[2 (-1)^{2/3}\right] \text{AiryBi}\left[2 (-1)^{2/3}\right]}{-\text{AiryAi}\left[2
    (-1)^{2/3}\right] \text{AiryBiPrime}\left[2 (-1)^{2/3}\right]}}%\)
    \end{equation}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You might use `\splitfrac`, but you should also do a few other things:

1. remove all the `\left` and `\right` directives that do no good;
2. change all `\text` directives to properly defined operator names;
3. give some more air to the lines.

Point 3 is accomplished by adding a phantom to the lines next to the fraction line.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}

\DeclareMathOperator{\AiryAi}{AiryAi}
\DeclareMathOperator{\AiryAiPrime}{AiryAiPrime}
\DeclareMathOperator{\AiryBi}{AiryBi}
\DeclareMathOperator{\AiryBiPrime}{AiryBiPrime}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\newcommand{\TB}{\vphantom{\Big|}}
y[x]=-\frac{
  \splitfrac{(-1)^{5/6} (\AiryAi[-(-1)^{2/3} (-2+i x)] \AiryBi[2 (-1)^{2/3}]}
            {-\AiryAi[2(-1)^{2/3}] \AiryBi[-(-1)^{2/3} (-2+i x)])\TB}
}{
  \splitfrac{\AiryAiPrime[2 (-1)^{2/3}] \AiryBi[2 (-1)^{2/3}]\TB}
            {-\AiryAi[2(-1)^{2/3}] \AiryBiPrime[2 (-1)^{2/3}]}
}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend writing like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

Let $c_0 \coloneqq (-1)^{2/3}$ and
\begin{align}
    y_1[x] &\coloneqq \mathrm{AiryAi}\left[-c_0 (-2+i x)\right] \mathrm{AiryBi}\left[2 c_0\right]\nonumber\\
    &\qquad -\mathrm{AiryAi}\left[2
c_0\right] \mathrm{AiryBi}\left[-c_0 (-2+i x)\right]\\
    y_2[x] &\coloneqq \mathrm{AiryAiPrime}\left[2 c_0\right] \mathrm{AiryBi}\left[2 c_0\right]\nonumber\\
    &\qquad -\mathrm{AiryAi}\left[2
    c_0\right] \mathrm{AiryBiPrime}\left[2 c_0\right],
\end{align}
we define
\begin{equation}
y[x]=-(-1)^{5/6}\frac{y_1[x]}{y_2[x]}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]